# How do I overwrite the page?

Tags: 7

I used the CCK module to create a content type that has three fields (title, description, and body). I want to overwrite two pages: one is where there is a "create content" navigation located on the left page; the other one is where I click  on "Create page" and which displays the form page.

Comment: You should explain better what you are trying to accomplish, and why. Normally, there isn't any reason to alter those system pages. The more details you give, the more specific the answer will be; differently the answer will be something like "create a custom module that implements `hook_menu_alter()`."

Comment: i want to overwrite the create page(a content type), which generated by the CCK module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter a node edit from, you need to create a custom module that implements [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6), using code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_form' == $form_id) {
    $node = $form['#node'];
    // ...
    // @todo Add the code you need.
    // ...
  }
}
```

For examples of actual implementations of `hook_form_alter()` that alter the node edit form, see [book_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--book--book.module/function/book_form_alter/6), [locale_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--locale--locale.module/function/locale_form_alter/6) (which alters also other forms), [menu_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_form_alter/6), [path_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--path--path.module/function/path_form_alter/6), and [taxonomy_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_form_alter/6).

Comment: form['type']['#value'] ,$form['#node'],$form['type']what're these variables meaning?

Comment: `$form['type']` is the form field containing the content type identifier; `$form['type']['#value']` contains the string that identifies the content type. `$form['#node']` contains the node object for the node being edited.